# Open graph not working, but showing "Redirecting to https://"

Tags: laravel, https, facebook-opengraph

I am getting a lot of pain with a small issue. My application https://mokapen.com is SSL certified and I added all open graph code:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="this is my title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="this is my description" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://mokapen.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://mokapen.com/image/cover-open-graph.jpg" />
```

But the strange behavior is that in Facebook the https://mokapen.com/it is showing error title "Redirecting to https://mokapen.com" and no image.

Do you think is an issue of Laravel Localization or htaccess?

Many thanks of any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your url has static value. Change url value with current url value

```
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ url()->full() }}" />
```

Ps: different laravel version has different url helpers

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply but I think your answer is not the solution. My OG works in other online tester, but not here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmokapen.com%2Fit

Comment: hi, when i checked your page's source code, i saw og:url was updated. So i share this link in my facebook timeline and it is working. No redirect, with image.

Comment: btw, if you want to change other fields such as image alt, please look up https://ogp.me/ image:alt

Comment: Hello, now it is working! I think Facebook didn't update the open graph cache. Thanks issue solved!